# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist While running in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver, automation, jenkins-pipeline, google-chrome-devtools

Starting ChromeDriver 89.0.4389.90 (62eb262cdaae9ef819aadd778193781455ec7a49-refs/branch-heads/4389@{#1534}) on port 30551
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
[ERROR] Tests run: 4, Failures: 2, Errors: 0, Skipped: 2, Time elapsed: 149.547 s <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
[ERROR] BrowserSelection(Cucumberoption.HomepageRunner)  Time elapsed: 149.258 s  <<< FAILURE!
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
System info: host: 'ip-172-31-49-149', ip: '172.31.49.149', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.4.0-1041-aws', java.version: '11.0.10'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
remote stacktrace: #0 0x562952783379

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Chrome browser version is compatible with your ChromeDriver version. Your ChromeDriver is 89.0.4389.90, so Chrome Browser version on your Jenkins agents should be 89 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Type your command here, but i think it occurs because you forgot to specify to run browser in headless mode

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).